# Message templates "access denied"

Tags: civimember, message-templates, user

I was trying to change the message template for the membership invoice, so I went to Administer - Communication - Message templates, but got the message "Access denied - you are not authorised to access this page". Anyone who knows what I can do and why access is denied?

Thank you.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without your CiviCRM version or CMS - or whether you're using an administrator (superuser) account. Ramesh's answer is broadly correct though.  Note that if you upgraded from < 4.6 to 4.6, where this became a separate permission, that would explain why a superuser account lacked this permission.

Answer (score 2):

your username has not got permission to Edit message template

so please try to view - Drupal Access Control

```
Administer -> Users and permissions -> Permissions(access control)
```

where you will see the following role and try to enable for your user group

> CiviCRM: edit message templates

If you don't have permission then please ask your admin or login to admin user and enable for specific user group

refer to link https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: I am getting this issue also with CiviCRM 4.7.15 on Drupal 7.50 with the superuser. Sure enough, the new permissions control was not selected to allow administrators. I noticed that whenever I save my changes, they don't stick.